# How to backup mysql database using query

Tags: mysql, backup, sqlyog

```
BACKUP DATABASE dbwebsite TO DISK 'C:\Users\Paeng\Desktop\mydatabase.sql';
```

It always says error

> Query : BACKUP DATABASE dbwebsite TO DISK 'C:\Users\Paeng\Desktop\mydatabase.sql'
>   Error Code : 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABASE dbwebsite TO DISK 'C:\Users\Paeng\Desktop\mydatabase.sql'' at line 1

Comment: check syntax. Review   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/20/sql-server-backup-database-command/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @RajatJaiswal the links you provided is for MS SQL Server. He is asking for MySQL

Comment: @RajatJaiswal yes im asking mysql database

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no SQL Statement for MySQL database to backup anymore like the syntax you are using and which is possible for MS SQL Server via TSQL.
For MySQL you have the following options to backup your database:

1. Use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-mysqldump.html) as a logical backup tool
2. Use MySQL Enterprise Backup if you have MySQL Enterprise Edition.
3. You can copy the MyISAM tables by just copying them.
4. You could also write a SQL script and copy the content of the tables into `txt` files by using the command: `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'fileName' FROM tableName`
5. You could of course also use replication or file system snapshots.
6. If you want to backup the database using vb.net (as mentioned in comments), you can use the following **MySqlBackup.NET**, which is an alternative to mysqldump. The web site and documentation can be found here: https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net

For more info read the MySQL documentation: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-methods.html).

Comment: thanks, #4 perfectly work but i need to backup database using query or using vb.net platform